# Semantic Versioning and Dependency Changes

Tags: c#, nuget, semantic-versioning

Some context: I'm working on a team which produces 6 different NuGet packages, which depend directly, and sometimes indirectly, on each other. Simply, we could have a situation like `p0 < p1 < p2`, where package `p0` depends on `p1`, which in turn depends on `p2`. We're trying to follow [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/) for these packages, but aren't quite sure what to do with `p0`'s version when `p1` or `p2` changes.

Here are some concrete examples:

- `p1` makes a breaking change (say `0.0.0` → `1.0.0`). We want to publish a version of `p0` which depends on `1.0.0`. Should this be a major or minor version bump for `p0`?
- `p1` makes a minor changes (`0.0.0` → `0.1.0`). Should this make a minor / patch version bump for `p0`?

More importantly,

> Is there any standard / consensus on how dependency version changes should affect package version changes?

Comment: If all the packages are dependent on each-other, why not roll them all into a single package? What's the case for maintaining them all as separate libraries?

Comment: There are many reasons for decoupling logic into separate libraries: 1) You can consume them independently (e.g. if some are .NET Standard 1.3 and some are .NET Standard 2.0, this is useful), 2) the underlying logic is clearly separated.

Comment: Semantic Versioning FAQ [What should I do if I update my own dependencies without changing the public API?](https://semver.org/#what-should-i-do-if-i-update-my-own-dependencies-without-changing-the-public-api)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Semantic versioning is all about what the change means *to the users of that library*. So if the change in `p1` doesn't cause a breaking change in `p0` then I don't see why it would require a major version bump in `p0`.

Basically, use whatever versions of dependent libraries work (remember that your users could be overriding them with different versions too, based on your dependency rules!), your versioning should only reflect what will affect your users.

**Warning, opinion based content ahead**

In my opinion, there's a fair bit of "caveat emptor" if you are directly using a transitive dependency (ie, using `p1` but only listing `p0` as a dependency) as a client of a library. This goes double when you have a *lot* of dependencies (as in most NPM packages) that go many, many layers down. I don't expect the authors of those libraries to keep track of all version changes of all transitive dependencies so I know to check.

Comment: What if the user is using both `p0` and `p1`, but only list `p0` as a dependency? They have the expectation that a upgrading to a new minor version of `p0` will not break them, but it does because it brings in a breaking change of `p1` that does affect them. Is the answer to this that everyone should only write code that uses packages they list as dependencies in their project and not use transitive dependencies directly in their own code? That sounds like a good idea to me, but I've never seen a static code analyser that warns when this happens, which makes me think it's not common.

Comment: @Ziv Using transitive dependencies directly is a pretty risky thing to do (though we certainly do it, especially with framework code, all the time). NPM will even warn you of such a thing (through the "peer dependency" concept). I'm just of the opinion that a breaking change in someone else's code does not mean a breaking change in yours.

Comment: In principal I agree, and I wish there was a FXCop rule for it for the .NET ecosystem (maybe there is and I don't know about it). However, in practise it doesn't work that way in .NET (original question tagged C# and NuGet). If I have a reference on xunit, it brings in several packages, one has the assert methods, another has attributes, I can't remember where the output helper is defined. Another example is Microsoft.AspNetCore.App. A web app would use types from dependency injection, settings/options, kestrel, MVC and other packages, without directly referencing those packages.

Comment: By the way, I hope my messages don't come off as arguing. I think it's a very interesting topic worth discussing. My interpretation of the original question included the scenarios from my first comment, so I think your answer would be improved by addressing it.

Comment: It's fair to note that Microsoft.AspNetCore.App is a "metapackage" that's explicitly designed to be "all these other packages, as one reference". I didn't realize you thought I should expound on this in the answer so I'll add it, and I didn't think you were being argumentative :) @Ziv

Answer (score 4):

In no way suggesting that @BradleyDotNET's excellent answer is insufficient. I just want to add my take on this.

> p1 makes a breaking change (say 0.0.0 → 1.0.0). We want to publish a version of p0 which depends on 1.0.0. Should this be a major or minor version bump for p0?

Yes, you are introducing a breaking change to users of p0.

> p1 makes a minor changes (0.0.0 → 0.1.0). Should this make a minor / patch version bump for p0?

If the additional interface from p1 is exposed in the p0 interface, then minor. If the dependency is at the implementation layer, then patch. The real question here is why are you taking this dependency change? If it's to add an interface to the p0 public surface, then it's a minor bump for p0, otherwise it's a patch level bump.

One more thing to consider here is what exactly you are applying version numbers to. Packages, libraries and interfaces are all different things and they can all be version independently. As BradleyDotNET points out, some packages contain collections of independently versioned artifacts. You may want to consider modifying your strategy such that your interfaces can have stable versions, despite frequent repackaging.

Answer (score 1):

This FAQ from semver.org answers both of your questions.

> What should I do if I update my own dependencies without changing the public API?
>
> That would be considered compatible since it does not affect the public API. Software that explicitly depends on the same dependencies as your package should have their own dependency specifications and the author will notice any conflicts. Determining whether the change is a patch level or minor level modification depends on whether you updated your dependencies in order to fix a bug or introduce new functionality. We would usually expect additional code for the latter instance, in which case it’s obviously a minor level increment.

See: https://semver.org/#what-should-i-do-if-i-update-my-own-dependencies-without-changing-the-public-api

A scenario described above is as,

```
app -> p0 -> p1
    -> p1
```

where,

```
app -> p0' -> p1'(breaking)
    -> p1
```

will give compilation errors in the app. The answer is clear that the app will need to manage its own dependencies. So it is a minor/patch bump.

Another scenario is where p1 is used transitively by the app, and p0 drops p1,

```
app -> p0 -> p1 // app uses p1 transitively
```

changes to,

```
app -> p0'      // p1 removed
```

the app will have compilation error.

Should it be a major bump? The above question answers above as well. It is a minor/patch bump.

Overall, the reason is that the authors of p0 are NOT going to know how the apps use p1. If a bump is major, we'll just see a lot of major bumps almost all the time, which adds friction in the process to bump.