# Nuget versioning when removing a dependency from package

Tags: nuget, semantic-versioning

Let's say I have a `PackageA` which has a package reference of `TransitiveDep`.

```xml
// PackageA's nuget refs
<PackageReference Include="TransitiveDep" Version="1.2.3" />
```

I have an app which uses `PackageA`, and `TransitiveDep` transitively.

```xml
// app, uses TransitiveDep transitively through PackageA
<PackageReference Include="PackageA" Version="2.3.4" />
```

There are no public methods in `PackageA` that expose `TransitiveDep` stuff.

Let's say I now have to remove the `TransitiveDep` package reference. The app will fail to build as-is, and will need to add a package reference for `TransitiveDep`. Is this considered a breaking change? Should I bump major or minor version of `PackageA`?

Comment: SemVer convention is based on the external API. If external API doesn't change, it's a Patch change. If it changes somewhat - Minor change. If it changes significantly - i.e. complete overhaul or something in the core functionality - Major. Difference between Major and Minor in practice is a bit subjective.

Answer (score 1):

What's being versioned is important.

In most environments that would be a breaking change. In order to use your product, dependents would have to be modified.

The spec can be interpreted along the lines of @taleodor's comment, but almost nobody applies versions to their interfaces alone.  SemVer tends to be used at the package level, where the "interface" is the package manifest.  In most cases, those list versions of dependencies, so modifying that in a way that breaks your customer's build requires a major version bump.

Comment: See my answer where it is not a major bump.

Comment: @hlpPy, breaking a build without warning is very bad practice.

Comment: What's the official documentation from nuget (Microsoft) on this where it says it is a bad practice? See also the accepted answer in here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53505965/semantic-versioning-and-dependency-changes/53506050#53506050. The angle is that the app is responsible for properly managing its own dependencies.

Comment: @hIpPy, if you read that thread, you'll find that I do not disagree with BradleyDotNet.  It really depends on your ecosystem and its capabilities.  Most tools, including Nuget (if memory serves), pull packages based on the supplied version range specifiers.  If you want to avoid breaking changes, you use something like [1.0.0, 2.0.0) and Nuget will take either the greatest or lowest package found in that range (switch dependent).

Comment: So if you publish a 1.x.y version that has a breaking transitive dependency, then you are going to break your consumer's build or possibly their product without notice.  They will not be happy with you and likely stop taking your updates.

Answer (score -1):

Ans: Bump minor version of PackageA.

> What should I do if I update my own dependencies without changing the public API?
>
> That would be considered compatible since it does not affect the public API. Software that explicitly depends on the same dependencies as your package should have their own dependency specifications and the author will notice any conflicts. Determining whether the change is a patch level or minor level modification depends on whether you updated your dependencies in order to fix a bug or introduce new functionality. We would usually expect additional code for the latter instance, in which case it’s obviously a minor level increment.

See: https://semver.org/#what-should-i-do-if-i-update-my-own-dependencies-without-changing-the-public-api

Comment: The OP is not versioning an API.  They are versioning a package, which may contain multiple API's and implementations, either of which may also be independently versioned within said package.  In most environments, that I am aware of, and particularly in the OP's stated silo (Nuget), taking a breaking change in a transitive dependency, requires a major version bump.

Comment: One of the many relevant discussion on SemVer/Semver: https://github.com/semver/semver/issues/502#issuecomment-1774377496